# How does $X^\flat$ transform?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

> I'm trying to figure out how the musically isomorphed tensor transforms under coordinate change from $x$ to $y$. The metric tensor $g$ is expressed in a local frame below or maybe dual frame not sure.

My attempt:

\begin{array}{ll}
X&=X(dx^i)\partial_i\\
X^\flat&=C(1,3)(g\otimes X)\\
&=C(1,3)(g(\partial_i\otimes\partial_j)X(dx^k)dx^i\otimes dx^j\otimes \partial_k)\\
&=g(\partial_i\otimes\partial_j)X(dx^k) dx^i(\partial_k)dx^j\\
&=g(\partial_i\otimes\partial_j)X(dx^i)dx^j\\
&=\partial_{y^i}x^a
\partial_{y^j}x^b
\partial_{x^c}y^i
g(\partial_{x^a}\otimes\partial_{x^b})X(dx^c)dy^j
\end{array}
C(1,3) is the contraction of slot 1 with slot 3.
I am stuck. I think there should only be one factor and not three, so I guess two of them are eachothers' inverses or something like that.

Another altenative is that I misinterpreted how the tensor should behave under a change of coordinates, perhaps the factors arise depending on what basis it is expressed in and not what indices are present.

It would seem I misinterpreted the formula. It is in fact the bases that should transform, not the components. So $\partial_{x^i}\mapsto\partial_{x^i}y^j\partial_{y^j}$ and $dx^i\mapsto \partial_{y^j}x^idy^j$ if I understood https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/change-of-variables-for-tensor-fields/ correct!

Comment: Please define all relevant quantities and notations, as it's currently pretty unclear what is happening here: Is $X$ supposed to be a vector? What is $C(1,3)$? What is the mixtures of $x$s and $y$s that suddenly appears at the end? How is this a physics question?

Comment: The raising and lowering of indices happens when you take differentials of different kinds which are how physics laws are usually written.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't see how this is a physics question (the answer is a straightforward application of the chain rule, and you have given no physical context whatsoever), and you still rely on the reader to guess without any context but the differential-geometry tag e.g. what $g$ is. Please try to word questions in such a way that they are easily accessible.

Comment: @ACuriousMind it has the metric tensor tag actually. I don't understand how it is not physics related since this is the mathematical framework a lot of physics is written in. Wow, you know the answer and do not write it? How unhelpful. Downvote if you want I don't see what else to do.

Comment: @Emil Just because something is used in physics doesn't mean it is a physics question. If you were doing a physics calculation and this step was part of it then it *could* be relevant but as it is, it is no different than an exercise in a pure mathematics text.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: For my part this question can be removed, it seems they are in fact inverses of eachother when they show up but in this case one could change basis after the contraction as well. @JamalS I will apply it to a physics problem after I understand it, a bit hard to apply something before understanding.